# ipython notebook 0.12.1 and 0.13.1 compatibility

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I created an ipython notebook with version 0.13.1 of ipython on fedora that works fine. When I try to read it on ipython 0.12.1 on opensuse I obtain a void white notebook. Is there a known problem on backward compatibility?
Both versions of ipython and friend modules run ok on each machine.
Thanks

Comment: The error message I got was "Unreadable JSON notebook" in one case, and "Invalid JSON data" in another case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython notebook versions are not backward compatible.  IPython 0.13.1 supports nbformat 3, while 0.12 only supports nbformat 2.  [Here is a script](https://gist.github.com/minrk/1935808) you can use to downgrade v3 notebooks to v2.  In future versions (0.13 included), you will get a better message when you try to open an unreadable notebook.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have an error message with the script. The messages is to long to put it here

Comment: ` $ python downgradenb.py RFG2.py
downgrading RFG2.py -> RFG2.v2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "downgradenb.py", line 43, in <module>
    map(downgrade_ipynb, sys.argv[1:])
  File "downgradenb.py", line 37, in downgrade_ipynb
    nb = current.read(f, 'json') ... 
... ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: to downgrade, the script must be run on a computer which can parse the *newer* version - it cannot be run against IPython 0.12.

Comment: yes, after my last message I tried on a machine with 0.13 version and of course it worked :-). Thanks

Comment: Note that IPython 0.13: a major new release, was made on June 30, 2012.  It's frustrating that people are posting example notebooks in this format without warning people that many platforms (e.g. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) will only have older versions for several more years.

Comment: IPython 0.12 was a short-lived first release of the notebook (it was only available for six months), and is fully deprecated. The LTS model is a tricky one, because not all packages that just happen to be in the LTS repo are actually suited to long-term support.